# Is there a way to make automatic database backups from Laravel Forge?

Tags: sql, database, laravel, forge

I have a few databases that are in Laravel Forge, and was wondering if anyone knew how to create automatic backups of the databases?

Comment: well you are a developer so you could develop a scheduled task to do it i supposed .. or even ask the people who run forge, you know since you pay for it

Comment: Ok will do and report the findings here. Thank you!

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/forge-backup-databases-with-cronjob?page=1   found this resource and will try to implement it, and then share the results.

Comment: https://forge.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/scheduler.html

Comment: https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/use-mysqldump-to-back-up-mysql-or-mariadb/

Answer (score 0):

From Laravel Forge, I would go in to Servers, and select the server I want. From the selected server, I can go in to Scheduler. In scheduler, there are three options, from Command
User
Frequency

The Command is where the cron job is inserted.
The User is the person who would have access to the databases that are requested.
The Frequency is how often this would happen.

These resources helped me figure it out
https://forge.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/scheduler.html
https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/use-mysqldump-to-back-up-mysql-or-mariadb/

and this discussion helps to find other resources
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/forge-backup-databases-with-cronjob?page=1

Then to access the files generated, this is a great resource to follow to create your first server, in order to know how to access the files that are generated.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04